# Como organizar dados de uma listview?

Tags: android, listview

Eu tenho uma list view de horarios onde diz o nome da linha, da paragem , horario e estado.

Se alguem me conseguir explicar como funciona a organização em android agradecia so preciso de saber como organanizar em ordem crescente e ascendente para por exemplo o campo do nome da linha.

O objectivo é por exemplo o que vi no stackoverflow inglês:

Unsorted:

```
Record  Color   Clothes
0       blue    shoes
1       yellow  pants
2       red     boots
3       black   coat
```

Sorted by Color:

```
Record  Color   Clothes
3       black   coat
0       blue    shoes
2       red     boots
1       yellow  pants
```

Sorted by Clothes:

```
  Record  Color   Clothes
    2       red     boots
    3       black   coat
    1       yellow  pants
    0       blue    shoes
```

So que para uma listview com os "ArrayList" so que com as duas ordem crescente e decrescente. 
O post inglês:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164795/how-to-sort-multiple-arrays-in-java)

**O meu código do meu list :**

```
 try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(myJSON);


            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject cursor = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String title = cursor.getString(TAG_TITLE);

                horarioHora.add(cursor.getString(TAG_TITLE));
                String estado = cursor.getString(TAG_DATESTART);
                horarioLinha.add(cursor.getString("linhaNome"));
                horarioParagem.add(cursor.getString("paragemRua"));
                HashMap<String, String> horario = new HashMap<>();
                horario.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                horario.put(TAG_DATESTART, estado);

                horarioList.add(horario);
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, horarioList, R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[]{TAG_TITLE, TAG_DATESTART},
                    new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.estado});
            listaHorarios.setAdapter(adapter);
            dialog.dismiss();
            Url = "http://dagobah.grifin.pt/tiagocoelho/utilizadorAndroid.php";
            funcao = "utilizador";

            get_data();
            listaHorarios.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            HorariosActivity.this);
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage("Quer adicionar o horário aos favoritos?")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Adicionar",


                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                            int id) {
                                            try {
                                                horarioitem = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).toString();
                                                Sthoras = horarioHora.get(position);
                                                Stlinhas = horarioLinha.get(position);
                                                Stparagens = horarioParagem.get(position);
                                                tvlinhas.setText(Sthoras);

                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }

                                            Url = "http://dagobah.grifin.pt/tiagocoelho/confirmaAddFavAndroid.php?Sthoras="+Sthoras+"&Stlinhas="+Stlinhas+"&Stparagens="+Stparagens+"&utilizadorId="+UtilizadorId2;
                                            Url=Url.replace(" ", "%20");
                                            funcao = "verificar";
                                            get_data();


                                        }
                                    });
                    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alert.show();

                }
            }); //end setOnItemClickListener
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Espero que me possam ajudar pois realmente pelo que já pesquisei não estou a conseguir entender a organização android.

Para o meu programa a organização não pode ser feita via php ou sql necessita ser mesmo feita por Android.

Comment: Você quer ordenar o array `horarioList`? Por que está a usar um *HasMap*? Em vez não pode usar uma classe cujas propriedades são as *keys* do *HasMap*?

Answer (score 1):

A ListView organiza os items na ordem em que você coloca nela, se os seus dados estão desordenados, muito provavelmente é por causa do Objeto JSON pois segundo a documentação http://www.json.org/

> Json Object is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs.

Desta forma, as bibliotecas são livres para reordenar ele como quiser, e no caso do Android, ele o faz (não me pergunte por que).

Já tive problemas com essa ordenação também, e a forma que encontrei para corrigir foi organizar a lista antes de inserir na lista, pegando a Key do Json e inserindo na posição "0", depois na posição "1" e assim por diante.

Algumas bibliotecas como o GSON mantém a ordem, é uma solução bem mais fácil do que tratar Key a Key (dependendo da quantidade de keys)

Answer (score -1):

Aqui está um modelo de listview com intens diferentes do seu:

```
var
TForm1: TForm;
ColIndex: Integer = 0;
OrdAsc : boolean = true;

//No evento OnColumnClick do ListView
  if ColIndex = Column.Index then
  begin
    // Se a coluna clicada eh a mesma que ja esta,
    // troca a ordem
    OrdAscCol := not(OrdAscCol);
    lvMicros.AlphaSort;
  end else
  begin
    // Sendo a coluna diferente da clicada anteriormente
    OrdAscCol := true;
    ColIndex:= Column.Index;
    lvMicros.AlphaSort;
  end;


//No evento OnCompare do ListView

  // Para reorganizar o ListView de acordo com a coluna clicada
  If ColIndex = 0 Then
  begin
    // Organização pelo caption do item de acordo com a ordem ascendente ou não
    if OrdAscCol then
      Compare:= CompareText(Item1.Caption, Item2.Caption)
    else
      Compare:= CompareText(Item2.Caption, Item1.Caption);
  end else
  begin
    // Organização pelos subitems, tb de acordo com a ordem ascendente ou não
    if OrdAscCol then
      Compare:= CompareText(Item1.SubItems[ColIndex-1],
                            Item2.SubItems[ColIndex-1])
    else
      Compare:= CompareText(Item2.SubItems[ColIndex-1],
                            Item1.SubItems[ColIndex-1]);

  end;
```

Comment: O AP fez a pergunta em Java. Responda em Java. Imagine que você faça uma pergunta em Delphi e eu lhe responda em PHP. Não lhe serviria de muita coisa.